# Dev and prod values in python

Tags: python, django

what i need is following in some class , when i am running it on local host vs running it on production

```
if __debug__:
return {'dbhost' : "localhost", 'dbuser' : "root", 'dbpass' : "", 'dbname' : "some_DB"}
else:
return {'dbhost' : "localhost", 'dbuser' : "appwork_ayurveda", 'dbpass' : "some_password", 'dbname' : "some_DB"}
```

I want to know if i am doing it right.

Also if it is not right then how can i perform following in dev vs prod environments

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', database='some_database')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a separate settings.py file for your development settings.

Aside from that, none of your settings files should be storing the password in raw text, the most common approach is to have your settings files reference environment variables that contain the database authentication settings.

If the only difference is a database password, then you could just use different values for the environment variables. But more than likely at some point you'll need to separate them further.

Comment: firstly i am concerned about dev and prod environments only , like in swift i can do #if DEBUG ...  else ...

Comment: @MandeepKumar - You could do `if settings.DEBUG:` but that gets messy very fast (and potentially error prone)

Comment: so what should be the solution if you can help me ?

Comment: You should have a separate settings.py file

Comment: yes i have a separate setting.py , sorry i am new to python , so i don't know how better i can use it